# разделения строки на подстроки

Tags: c, строки

Припустим у меня есть массив чаров str, который имеет буквы, пропуски и цифры. Мне нужно подсчитать количество подстрок которые разделённые двумя пробелами(В данном примере это Karmen, MIT Press, 1990), значит в переменной count должно быть число 3, но почему-то там 0. Подскажите, почему?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[255] = "Karmen  MIT Press  1990";
    
    int i = 0;
    int count =0;
    while(!str[i])
    {
        if(str[i] ==" " && str[i+1] == " ")
        {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(count != 0) count++;
    printf("%i", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что как минимум нельзя сравнивать символы со строками:

```
if(str[i] ==" " && str[i+1] == " ")
```

Надо

```
if(str[i] == ' ' && str[i+1] == ' ')
```

Еще - цикл

```
while(!str[i])
```

заканчивается на первом же ненулевом символе! Надо

```
while(str[i])
```

Ну и у вас есть такая неприятность - например, что будет, если слова разделены тремя пробелами? По заданию их вроде бы считать не надо (эти подстроки разделены **не** двумя пробелами), а у вас они посчитаются за две...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки верно описаны [в другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226719/416121), а мне осталось показать другой способ решать задачу - конечный автомат.

Бежим по строке. `spaces_in_row` - хранит количество пробелов подряд. Если текущий символ не пробел, то `spaces_in_row` обнуляется, иначе увеличивается на единицу.

Если текущий символ не пробел и `spaces_in_row` ровно два, то мы пробежали мимо разделителя. В этом случае увеличиваем счётчик `delimiters`.

Надо как-то обработать пробелы в начале и в конце строки. В этом решении они игнорируются. В начале пробелы пропускает конструкция `str + strspn(str, " ")`. В конце специальной обработки не нужно:

```
// gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra substrings.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_substrings(const char *str) {
    int delimiters = 0;
    int spaces_in_row = 0;
    for (const char *p = str + strspn(str, " "); *p != '\0'; ++p) {
        if (*p == ' ') {
            ++spaces_in_row;
        } else {
            if (spaces_in_row == 2) {
                ++delimiters;
            }
            spaces_in_row = 0;
        }
    }
    return delimiters + 1;
}

void test(const char *str) {
    printf("%d \"%s\"\n", count_substrings(str), str);
}

int main()
{
    test("Karmen  MIT Press  1990");
    test(" a  b ");
    test("  a  b  ");
    test("a b  c   d");
    test("  ");
    test("");
}
```

> ```
> 3 "Karmen  MIT Press  1990"
> 2 " a  b "
> 2 "  a  b  "
> 2 "a b  c   d"
> 1 "  "
> 1 ""
> ```